How to deal with long cache keys
I have a caching method that generates long cache keys by concatenating a string list of price codes.
var cacheKey = "SalesPrice_" + string.Join("_", priceCodeList);

There can be 50+ priceCodes which leads to the cache key being too long. I am looking for a way to efficiently shorten this cache key by keeping the uniqueness.
Is there a way to solve this?
Edit: PriceCodeList is a string query parameter list for a web api i use. So I cannot cache each price code separately. This long string must be used.

too long for what? most caches are fairly forgiving about key length, within reason; and: what is priceCodeList ? If this is Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache, note that the key there is object, not string, so: if priceCodeList is some custom type that supports equality (and is immutable): you could literally just use priceCodeList as the cache key; so again: what is priceCodeList ?

Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question. It is a string list. I don't want to run into a performance issue with a key that is more than 800 characters long. Caching works better with short and unique keys

At the current time, I'm probably "the person" for dealing with the main caching primitives in .NET, on behalf of MSFT. I disagree with your reasoning here, and I'd want to see evidence for that statement. Especially for an in-process cache, I wouldn't be hugely concerned with an 800 character cache key, because string hashing doesn't necessarily consider every character. I might be concerned about the constant allocation, so: if there's a way to reduce that size (using short-codes/ids instead of long codes, if possible, for example), it might be interesting.

But equally: if the cache is guarding something more expensive than the 800 character key, it might still be very effective. You could also consider caching the 50 items separately, rather than per list (in the "hit" case, 50 in-process cache hits could be stupidly fast, and it wouldn't require concatenation or other allocation)

I agree with your points Marc and unfortunately I don't have any evidence that proves that shorter keys improve performance. However, I would like to ask again, then, what is maximum key size that a cache key can hold without runnin to any error? @MarcGravell

Why you want to use the items that you store as a cache key? Isn't it posssible to create kind of a container or group which has an identifier and use that? Where do you get the prices from? What if you want to store 500k prices in future, this approach doesn't scale.

@TimSchmelter in my head, I'm thinking "Redis hash using the code as the field, HMGET"

@Serhat discussed below

EDIT: Per @MarcGravell 's findings, hashing cache keys slows the performance and might lead to hash collisions. Therefore my answer below does not address the question perfectly - even more - introduces new pitfalls (please read comments for more context).
Therefore, I would try to pass this long string as cache key directly to cache and monitor it regularly in case of any error. Hope that it works as expected.
I am keeping the question and answer for future reference.
PS: Please do not downvote the answer as - even though it is not relevant - it includes valuable take-aways. :)

I have come across hashing. I could pass a long string and it could shorten it for me by keeping uniqueness.
Here is the code that does that:
private static string GetHashedCacheKey(string key)
{
    using var md5 = MD5.Create();
    var inputAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    var hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputAsBytes);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var byt in hashBytes)
    {
        sb.Append(byt.ToString("X2")); // X2 ensures upper case hexadecimal characters
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

How to use it:
var cacheKey = "SalesPrice_" + string.Join("_", priceCodeList);
var hashedKey = GetHashedCacheKey(cacheKey);
await _memoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(hashedKey, async entry =>
     {
         entry.SetOptions(cacheEntryOptions);
         return await value();
     });

One thing that you should be super careful about is that since you register your cache with a hashed key, you must also do other operations with this hashed key.
In other words, all CRUD operations must be with the hashed key if you decide to implement this. So remember to hash your key before a cache operation takes place.

EDIT: OBS! Hash collisions can occur in this setting. So, if you want to implement this solution, you'd need to be super careful; for example, you might choose to include the original key in the payload, so that you can at least detect collisions and act as though it was a "miss", rather than using the wrong data. [Credits: @Marc Gravell]

hash collisions are a real thing, so: if you want to do this, you'd need to be super careful; for example, you might choose to include the original key in the payload, so that you can at least detect collisions and act as though it was a "miss", rather than using the wrong data

That's an amazing catch! i will include this to my answer. Thanks for that

Still an unintentional collision with MD5 is very low. Like one in a novemdecillion.

second viewing: I strongly suspect this is an anti optimization; you've gone from a simple string concat and hash (which to emphasize: does not necessarily look at every character), to: do the same string concat, then run it through an Encoding, which does look at every character, allocating a byte[], then running each byte through ToString(), then running those bytes through MD5 and allocating a byte[], then allocating a string for each hash byte, and a string for the final key: I would be simply amazed if this was an improvement in any way

@Magnus funny story... it turns out that an intentional and credible attack vector is for an attacker to provide deliberately chosen input data to force hash collisions, to exploit a site

I think the only reason to use Hashing for the key is out of memory concerns. If the strings are very large and you hold millions of them in memory.

@Magnus there are other ways of addressing that, though

currently "racing my horses" via https://gist.github.com/mgravell/f6082624290d14f44068a42e20a9b7db - need to head out though, will update with results if they arrive

added results; 114 times slower for 10 chars, 12 times slower for 100 chars, 4.2 times slower for 800 chars; also significant allocs

Why not use a Guid for cache key (I mean any synthetic key)?

I would like to ask again, then, what is maximum key size that a cache key can hold without runnin to any type of error (OutOfMemoryException, SlowRetriavalTime etc.)?

MD5 hashes are only 128bits. So basically, hashing only values that are 129 bits worth of information will already give you a 1:2 chance of hash collisions. Assuming the key string to be MD5-hashed is only composed of uppercase letters A-Z (which is almost 5 effective bits), then you are reaching this 1:2 collision chance already when mostly using key strings of 26 uppercase letters or longer (which is possibly the case presented in the question).

@Serhat OOM is also a function of "how many"; there's  no single answer - everything is contextual. As I already mentioned, my first thought here is "short codes"; for 50 tokens to be 800 chars means each code must be ~15 long (plus spacers); is there some other (perhaps artificial) shorter code that can be used per price code? Heck, base-64 (trimmed) of the rowid might do, ideally stored explicitly. Re slow retrieval: your method is (per evidence above) much slower so, :shrug:

Thanks for the remarks @MarcGravell . PriceCodeList is actually a string list that consists of query parameters to an endpoint. So i wanted to make it a big single string object and store it as key. As per your answers, I will abort my mission of hashing that as we can have max 1000 string length and that does not impact performance. Well, if it does, then we will try to find another way to cache / improve :)

I appreciate everyone's input. Thank you alot for assisting me with this problem.
@MarcGravell no, there is unfortunately no way for me to shorten these values

@Serhat the takeaway from this is to not make assumptions and not rush to fix something you only assume is broken. I encountered a similar case once, where someone used Couchbase with GUID keys and zipped contents to reduce space over millions of entries per day - entries that were expensive to produce and impossible to regenerate. And guess what - they were compressing the GUID for years instead of the content

Yeah! Even with 7 years of experience one still makes mistakes like this. I am learning and improving every day. Assumptions are usually not good in these field. I should use more benchmarking methods like Marc does. Maybe that's why he works at microsoft and i still struggle with everyday issues :) Thanks
